# Jquery if hasClass then trigger click

Tags: jquery, function, if-statement, triggers, click

thanks for having a look at this, basically I'm quite new to jQuery and what im trying to do is when the a#category-all link is clicked I want only the child links with the class "selected" to trigger a click. At the moment every a element on that level is getting clicked. Thanks for your help.

```
$('li a#category-all').click(function()
{
    if($(this).parent().siblings().find('a').hasClass('selected'))
    {
        $(this).parent().siblings().find('a').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are multiple `<a>`s, you can make this both work and work more efficiently by doing:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().find('a.selected').click();
```

As you have it, `hasClass` will just check if any *one* of the links is selected, then click all of them.

This might work, too:

```
$('#category-all').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('ul').find('.selected').click();
});
```